# how to use find in a JSON

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I have this JSON

```
{
    "_id": "586baa68734d1d7bf4f06432",
    "topic": 1,
    "story": {
        "2016-01-01": 152,
        "2016-01-02": 203,
        "2016-01-03": 419,
        "2016-01-04": 792,
        "2016-01-05": 457,
        "2016-01-06": 350,
        "2016-01-07": 666
       }
}
```

this function prints out this JSON

```
exports.getData = function(req, res){
    Top10.find({},function(err, docs){
        console.log("docs "+docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
}
```

now I want to get the NUMBER for a specific date - lets say 2016-01-01 I want to get back 152

how do I do that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: `docs["story"]["2016-01-01"]`

Comment: @JonasKöritz
thanks for your answer!
I tried         console.log("docs "+docs["story"]['2016-01-01']);
and it still not working

Answer (score 2):

To access the nested element try something like:

```
var date = "2016-01-01";
var number = docs["story"][date];
```

If docs is an array (to access the first element):

```
var date = "2016-01-01";
var numbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
     if(docs[i]["story"][date]) {
         numbers.push(docs[i]["story"][date]);
     }
}
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: what is inside docs? Can you post a dump of the docs variable?

Comment: So docs is an array, my second code-block should work then. If you want all items of the array you will have to walk the docs array in a loop.

Comment: @JonasKöritz can we get all items of the array?

Comment: @JonasKöritz I tried your code but it write to me an error: "cannot read property '2016-01-01' of undefind'

Comment: @JonasKöritz yee got you